# How many unique orders of length n are there where the index number is different from the number itself?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Suppose you pick a random order of consecutive numbers from 1 to $n$.
The order for a series of $n$ numbers would then be:
$$
x_1,  x_2,  ... x_{n-1} , x_n
$$

The amount of unique combinations is of course $n!$.
e.g. for $n=3$ there are $3!$ (or 6) unique combinations, see table below.

We are interested in the combinations where $x_i \neq i$.

| C | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| <strike>1</strike> | <strike>1</strike> | <strike>2</strike> | <strike>3</strike> |
| <strike>2</strike> | <strike>1</strike> | 3 | 2 |
| <strike>3</strike> | 2 | 1 | <strike>3</strike> |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| <strike>6</strike> | 3 | <strike>2</strike> | 1 |

> Note: The 'wrong' combinations have been striked.

We see that there are 2 valid combinations.

We can now continue this list until $n$.
Eg. for $n=4$, there are 9 valid combinations and so on.

| Magnitude | Total Combinations | Valid Combinations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | **0** |
| 2 | 1 | **1** |
| 3 | 6 | **2** |
| 4 | 24 | **9** |
| 5 | 120 | **44** |
| ... | ... | ... |
| $n$ | $n!$ |  |

Obviously we would like a general solution for length $n$.
Who can help to calculate this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: With such questions (where you already have the first members of some sequence), you should first look it up in the OEIS (http://oeis.org/).

Comment: You are counting derangements here, the formula is well known.

Comment: Thank you, I end up with http://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C1%2C2%2C9%2C44 which is still pretty unclear and does not describe this case.

Comment: I do not know why you are not happy with the OEIS entry. Its title explains what it is about, and it is what you asked for. The "Formula" section tells many ways of calculating the numbers.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen: You're absolutely right! Seems like I'm an idiot :-) (I could no longer edit my first comment.) Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GordonRoyle pointed out: this is a description of derangements...

For a series $n$, the number of derangements are
$$
n!\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}
$$

As @JukkaKohonen pointed out, there is a nice entry in the [OEIS database](http://oeis.org/A000166).

Thanks all!